# Why isn't ts-jest loading my custom tsconfig file?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library, ts-jest

For some reason, my custom tsconfig file isn't being picked up in jest.config.ts. Here is my jest.config.ts:

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [`./jest.setup.ts`],
  testEnvironment: `jsdom`,
  roots: [
    `<rootDir>/test`
  ],
  testMatch: [
    `**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)`,
    `**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)`
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": `ts-jest`
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: `tsconfig.jest.json`
    }
  }
}
```

I know that other parts of this config ARE being applied. For example, if I remove the keys above globals my tests don't run. Also, I know that the change specified in my tsconfig.jest.json file is the necessary change to fix my tests because if I make the same change in my main tsconfig.json file my tests run fine.

I've also tried putting to desired tsconfig compiler options directly into the jest.config.ts file, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [`./jest.setup.ts`],
  testEnvironment: `jsdom`,
  roots: [
    `<rootDir>/test`
  ],
  testMatch: [
    `**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)`,
    `**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)`
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": `ts-jest`
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: {
        jsx: `react`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Updated answer for jest@29 (released August 2022) and ts-jest@29 (released September 2022)**

All of my React component `*.tsx`-related tests were broken after upgrading Jest-and-friends to version 29. I also received error messages that `jestConfig.globals['ts-jest']` is now deprecated.

1. As per the [ts-jest "Options" doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/#options) you need to use the lowercased `tsconfig` and not the camel-cased `tsConfig`.
2. As per the [ts-jest "TypeScript Config option" doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/tsconfig/) you should modify your Jest config to `jestConfig.transform['regex_match_files']`.

The relevant parts of my project's configuration are below. (Caveat: note that I'm using a custom location for my config files, i.e. a dedicated `./config/` directory in the project root, but the principle of specifying the relative-path-to-config-file remains the same).

```json
// ./package.json
// (trimmed to just the relevant parts)
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --config=./config/.jestrc.js --rootDir=./src/"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^29.0.1",
  "jest": "^29.0.3",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.3",
  "ts-jest": "^29.0.0",
  "typescript": "^4.8.3"
}
```

```js
// ./config/.jestrc.js
// (trimmed to just the relevant parts)
transform: {
  '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
    'ts-jest',
    // required due to custom location of tsconfig.json configuration file
    // https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/tsconfig
    {tsconfig: './config/tsconfig.json'},
  ],
},
```

Comment: This helps me a lot when updating to Jest@v29. Thank you!

Comment: I just spent three hours finding out that the regex listed in `transform` _must_ be _exactly_ `^.+\\.tsx?$` without any variations at all.  I thought I was being clever removing the `x?` because I am not using JSX, but no.  I am not clever.

Comment: true that is very strange I'm not sure what's going on since I did a variable on tsx? with ^.+\\.(tsx?)$ and ^.+\\.\\(tsx?\\)$ and it didn't work so I'm not sure what's going on. If this is a true regex it should be working unless ? is not working how I think it's working in normal regex.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen, @arcanereinz, also check that the `preset` property is not present in the jest configuration file, if you use a recent `ts-jest` (ver 29+) it will conflict with the transforms specified below (see the ts-jest [doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets)).

Answer (score 16):

the correct key is `tsconfig` not `tsConfig`.

Comment: Struggled this for so long the other day because of also finding that dumb documentation (https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/) leading you down a cliff.  tsConfig gets ignored, tsconfig works.  Official documentation is https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started.

Comment: @Matriarx yep, the exact same thing happened to me. Hopefully this question ends up in people's google results

Comment: You should see a warning about this `(WARN) "[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.tsConfig" is deprecated, use "[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.tsconfig" instead.`